# How to create an instance of a class?

Tags: android, class, instance

I have this class, and i want to use its methods in my main activity, how can i create an instance?

```
public class BDD {
...
    public boolean insertarGuia(String g, String d) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how can i create an instance of it ?". Do you want to implement a constructor, or do you want to create a new instance to call the method? If it is the latter, then it's a basic Java problem, `BDD bdd = new BDD();`. Or perhaps you want to make the method as `static`?

Comment: why does it show "Class file editor... source not found" when i step over using the debbuger?

Answer (score 2):

Create an instance of that class with the 'new' keyword in your main activity and then invoke those methods on that object.

```
BDD bdd = new BDD();
boolean value = bdd.insertarGuia("foo", "bar");
```

Or make the methods static

Change

```
public boolean insertarGuia(String g, String d) {
```

to

```
public static boolean insertarGuia(String g, String d) {
```

and in your main method have

```
boolean value = BDD.insertaGuia("foo", "bar");
```

Comment: why does it show "Class file editor... source not found" when i step over using the debbuger?

Comment: Without knowing where you set your break point or what you are stepping over/into I can only speculate. But I assume it's because you are stepping over an Android method for which you have no attached source files.

Comment: `BDD bdd = new BDD();`, there

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy, just create an object of your class and call any of the method in your activity:

```
BDD obj = new BDD();
obj.ArregloGuias();
```

Comment: when we use instance we do not need to "new Class" and it don't capture heapmemory